Weird Python Error "TypeError: an integer is required" on a List - Only in Debugger - Fixed by adding print
I have a rather strange error in the following code:
CUSTOMER_ORDER = ["Some", "Customers"]
ticket_types = ["analysis_tickets"] # is list because copied from legacy code and only need 1 type here (TODO replace with str.)

[...]

# Get all  tickets of each type for each customer of the month
for customer in CUSTOMER_ORDER:
    all_tickets[customer] = {}

    for ticket_type in ticket_types:
        logger.info("Getting '" + ticket_type + "' for customer " + customer + "...")

        if ticket_type == "analysis_tickets":
            suffix = ANALYSIS_TICKETS_SUFFIX
        elif ticket_type == "support_tickets":
            suffix = SUPPORT_TICKETS_SUFFIX
        elif ticket_type == "engineering_tickets":
            suffix = ENGINEERING_TICKETS_SUFFIX

        all_tickets[customer][ticket_type] = {}
        all_tickets[customer][ticket_type]["tickets"] = []

        try:
            response = requests.get(
                OTRS_URL + "/TicketSearch",
                params={
                    "UserLogin": OTRS_USER,
                    "Password": OTRS_PW,
                    "Queues": customer + suffix,
                    time_older: datetime.datetime.now(),
                    time_newer: datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=TIME_RANGE_DAYS),
                    "Limit": 3000,
                },
                verify=False,
            )
            if response.status_code != 200:
                logger.error("Could not get tickets for customer " + customer + ". Error: " + str(response.status_code))
                sys.exit(1)

            if "TicketID" not in response.json():
                logger.warning("No tickets found for customer " + customer + " amd ticket type '" + ticket_type + "'.")
                all_tickets[customer][ticket_type]["tickets"] = []
            else:
                all_tickets[customer][ticket_type]["tickets"] = response.json()["TicketID"]
                logger.info("Found " + str(len(all_tickets[customer][ticket_type]["tickets"])) + " tickets for customer " + customer + " and ticket type '" + ticket_type + "'.")
                ticket_count += len(all_tickets[customer][ticket_type]["tickets"])

            # print(ticket_type + " " + ticket_types)
        except Exception as e:
            logger.error("Could not get tickets for customer " + customer + ". Error: " + traceback.format_exc())
            sys.exit(1)

Error:
Code errors: Exception has occurred: TypeError
an integer is required  File "C:\Users\user\Documents\GitLab\various-scripts\OTRS Auto-Reporting\Analysts-Locked\otrs_reporting_analysts_locked.py", line 160, in <module>
    for ticket_type in ticket_types:
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: an integer is required

However I was able to fix the issue by either:

uncomment the print statement at the end of the try block
removing the try/except block
running the script directly without debugger

And now I am completely confused. Why is the print statement doing anything? Why does it error with the debugger but works fine without? What has all this to do with an expected integer?
Can anyone make sense of this?
I am using Python 3.12.7 64 bit ( Microsoft Store) and the respective VS-Code plugin.

"uncomment the print statement at the end of the try block": that print function has a problem (concatenating a string with a list won't work), but that's not what this error shows. That's simply another error in the code.

If things work because you remove things below the offending line, and this is in a loop, it may be that you assign some value to ticket_types inside the loop.

Which debugger are you using? I don't know VS Code that well, let alone any plugins; does the plugin state what debugger it uses? Can you try another debugger?

"except Exception as e:": traditaional warning that this is considered bad code, catching all errors.

Similarly, concatenating strings with + in a print or logger function is bad code: use the comma in a print function, use %s and the like with a set of arguments in a logging call (e.g. logger.warning("No tickets found for customer %s and ticket type %s.", customers, ticket_type)).

The actual error message doesn't make any sense to me, tbh. It feels like something else is going on; or this is a (very) bad debugger.

@9769953

"uncomment the print statement at the end of the try block": that print function has a problem (concatenating a string with a list won't work), but that's not what this error shows. That's simply another error in the code

Yeah I copied the wrong print statement sorry the actual line is print(ticket_type + " " + str(ticket_types)) but that should change anything about the actual issue.

if things work because you remove things below the offending line, and this is in a loop, it may be that you assign some value to ticket_types inside the loop.

But as you see - I don't


"except Exception as e:": traditaional warning that this is considered bad code, catching all errors. –
its just there to properly print any error and exit in any case so its not bad code


@9769953 The actual error message doesn't make any sense to me, tbh. It feels like something else is going on; or this is a (very) bad debugger.
Yeah thats what the question is about. Its the normal VS-Code Python debugger nothing fancy.

"Its the normal VS-Code Python debugger": which I don't know. Is it the Python built-in pdb debugger, or something else? Can you find out? If it's a VS Code plugin, which plugin?

@9769953 its https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.debugpy which uses debugpy (https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy)

Well, then it's just a few steps to follow the link to the repository, click on "issues" and find the second open issue: https://github.com/microsoft/debugpy/issues/1733 . Looks like a patch is incoming.

Yes I found this too but I don't think that's the actual issue
